# React Native TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: android, reactjs, mobile, expo, native

I have been working on moving a legacy react native mobile app to expo and I am stuck on this. Any ideas?

Here is what the console gives me:

```
Unable to start your application. Please refer to https://expo.fyi/no-registered-application for more information.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:null in console.warn
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:null in registerWarning
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:null in warnImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:null in console.warn
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:null in warn
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:null in runApplication
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Here is the contents of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "[appname]", //hiding the actual app name
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "eas-build-pre-install": "npm config set legacy-peer-deps true"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "2.4.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "3.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@unpourtous/react-native-search-list": "^2.1.1",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.3.2",
    "expo": "^38.0.0",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^3.18.0",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "native-base": "2.12.1",
    "qs": "^6.8.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-calendar-events": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.209.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
    "react-native-flexi-radio-button": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-google-fit": "^0.9.14",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.24.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.12.3",
    "react-native-media-controls": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "8.x.x",
    "react-native-modal-popover": "^0.0.12",
    "react-native-music-control": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-open-maps": "^0.3.6",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-pdf": "^5.1.7",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-picker": "^4.3.7",
    "react-native-pie": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-print": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-quick-actions": "^0.3.13",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-secharts": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-shadow-cards": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-storage": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-tab-navigator": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-tree-select": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-universal-pedometer": "smekalka/react-native-universal-pedometer",
    "react-native-url-preview": "^1.1.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-webview": "9.4.0",
    "react-native-yt-player": "^1.0.6",
    "react-navigation": "1.5.8",
    "rn-apple-healthkit": "^0.6.5",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.16",
    "teaset": "^0.6.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.9",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "flow-bin": "^0.142.0",
    "flow-remove-types": "^2.142.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

I ran npx react-native info and npx react-native doctor. Fixed what issues appeared there. Except it still doesn't seem to find the android sdk or react-native-windows.